# Different Jquery Mobile pages for Different Items

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working on an image board App using Jquery Mobile and planned to use Disqus in it. My index page loads an image and when user clicks on an image a new page is supposed to open which is dedicated to that Page. When I used PHP, it was simple to pass the parameter Using GET method as in:

```
/item.php?ID=3
```

But I am facing trouble to do it in HTML5 app using Jquery Mobile.

Comment: Check out these demo pages: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages/  and http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages-multi-page/index.html

Comment: Yes but like in case of ID i can fetch data from server but using this how can i get data from server per image.

Comment: Sorry for late replay, but in case you still need help for this, I suggest you store information about the next page within the image tag, see this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/rdpjxxnd/1/).